# Application of Hahn Banach Separation theorem, showing inclusion of ball

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

> Suppose $X,Y$ are normed spaces and $T:X\to Y$ is bounded. Suppose further that $\exists r>0$ such that $\|T^{*}f\|\ge r\|f\| \;\;\;\forall f\in Y'$ where $T^{*}:Y'\to X'$ is given by $T^{*}(f)=f\circ T$. Show that $B_Y(r)$, the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $0$ is contained in $C:=\overline{T(B_X)}$ where $B_X$ is closed unit ball in $X$.

I think this is about HST ( Hahn Banach Separation theorem).

Attempt: Suppose that there is $y_0\in B_Y(r)\setminus C$. Then separation theorem states that there is $f \in Y'$ such that

$$
\Re f(y_0) > \sup_{c\in C} \Re f(c)
$$

But also

$$
\Re f(y_0) \le |f(y_0)| \le \|f\| \|y_0\| \le \|f\| r \le \|T^{*} f\|
$$

and I'm stuck. I wanted to somehow show contradiction, but it seems I'm not going anywhere with my plan.

It'd be nice if someone can show how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

To arrive to a contradiction, you also  need to compute $\|T^*f\|$:

$$\|T^*f\|=\sup\{T^*f(x): x\in B_x\}= \sup \{ f(Tx): x\in B_x\} \leq \sup  f(\overline{T(B_X)}).$$ Then you combine it with the two inequalities that you already wrote.

Comment: combining the results I get $\sup\{\Re f(y):y\in C\} < \sup\{|f(y)|:y\in C\}$, but how is this a contradiction? (in real normed space this is a contradiction but maybe not in complex one?)

Comment: You have a point here. I am not sure how to proceed in the complex case...